# TypeScript Generics declararation syntax

Tags: typescript

In the code below what is the meaning of Action = Action?

```
export type ActionReducerMap<T, V extends Action = Action> = {
  [p in keyof T]: ActionReducer<T[p], V>;
};
```

Comment: Can we see the definition of `Action` (and `ActionReducer` would be nice)? In any case, `V` is anything that extends Action, but if no type is provided for `V`, `Action` is used as the default. I interpret it as, "V can be an `Action`, or something more specific, and it will be treated as a generic `Action` if you don't provide something more specific."

Answer (score 1):

It's generic parameter which is constrained to extend `Action` (i.e. it can be `Action` or any subclass of `Action`), and its default value, if not supplied, is `Action`.

Say you declare:

```
const myReduceMap : ActionReducerMap<SomeType> = ...
```

omitting the second generic type parameter, here it will default to `Action`.

Answer (score 0):

V extends Action - this means that V must be a type that extends Action.

= Action -> this means if a type V is not provided then the default will be Action itself.